# Syntactic ambiguity of adjective/adverb

Tags: syntax, ambiguity

"The bleak cadance of last month's inauguration was **still** in the air, **when** Trump lobbed the first Molotov cocktail of policies and executive orders against the capital’s brilliant-white porticos....."

In the above phrase, I can show 'still' can be represented as an adjectival or adverbial phrase (ambiguous), however is there a way to prove it is an adverb that relates to 'when' in the following clause?

Comment: You can show that it is possible to rearrange the sentence differently according to which interpretation you give it. So if "still" means something like "not moving" and as an adjective, then you could modify it with an adverb such as "very" or "absolutely". This is not possible with the Adv reading. The adverb *still* could be moved to the end of the first clause (but the adjective couldn't): "The bleak cadance of last month's inauguration was in the air still". This is because in this reading *still* is an Adjunct, where as in the Adj reading it is the Head of the Predicative Complement ...

Comment: ... of the verb *BE*. There's loads of other little nifty tricks like that you could pull.